# Refactoring 2 Regexps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, split, curly-braces

I want to split the string

```
smartcode = '{{question.answer}}'
```

to obtain just eventually

```
'answer'
```

I know this works

```
smartcode.split(/\{{(.*?)\}}/).last.split(/\.(?=[\w])/).last
```

but it's not the better way i guess...

Comment: And if there is no `.` inside the braces? Like in `{{question}}`? What do you need to get then? Also, can the handlebars contain other (single) curly braces inside?

Comment: Can we generalize the problem a bit? Are you always interested in the part behind the `.`? Is there always a `.` in the string? Is the string always surrounded by two curly brackets? Is it possible that there are numbers, symbols or whitespace in the string?

Comment: the smartcode is like a code to create a pdf document

Comment: It always has to be '{{question.answer}}'

Comment: Use `smartcode[/{{[^{}]*\.([^{}]*)}}/, 1]`

Comment: @Steph _"It always has to be '{{question.answer}}'"_ – can you elaborate? If it is the same static value, you don't need a regexp because the result would always be "answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest:

```
smartcode = '{{question.answer}}'
smartcode.match(/\.(\w+)/)[1]
#=> "answer"
```

Or when you want to ensure that the specific structure with the surrounding brackets and two words separated by a dot:

```
smartcode.match(/{{\w+\.(\w+)}}/)[1]
#=> "answer"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow your answer to be complex you should rather not go for `\w+` but rather `/.*\.(.*?)\}/` (basically that would match anything between a `.` and a `}`

ex:

```
> smartcode = '{{question.complex answer w/ more than 1 kind of symbols such as $}}'
> smartcode.match(/\.(\w+)/)[1]
=> "complex"
> smartcode.match(/.*\.(.*?)\}/)[1]
=> "complex answer w/ more than 1 kind of symbols such as $"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```rb
smartcode[/{{[^{}]*\.([^{}]*)}}/, 1]
```

The `/{{[^{}]*\.([^{}]*)}}/` regex (see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XRWYsj/1)) matches

- `{{` - a `{{` text
- `[^{}]*` - any zero or more chars other than `{` and `}` as many as possible
- `\.` - a dot
- `([^{}]*)` - Group 1 (this substring will be returned with the `[/regex/, num]` construct): any zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`, as many as possible
- `}}` - a `}}` text.

See the [Ruby code online](https://ideone.com/IfiuLp):

```rb
smartcode = '{{question.answer}}'
puts smartcode[/{{[^{}]*\.([^{}]*)}}/, 1]
# => answer
```

If you need to get multiple matches, use `.scan`:

```rb
smartcode = '{{question.answer}} and {{question.author}}'
puts smartcode.scan(/{{[^{}]*\.([^{}]*)}}/)
# => ['answer', 'author']
```

See [this Ruby code demo](https://ideone.com/nWIC1i).